# Removing expressions from QString using QRegExp

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm having an issue removing expressions from a QString using QRegExp. I tried a countless number of regex to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Sample Text (QString myString) In this instance, myString contains "\u0006\u0007\u0013Hello".

```
myString.remove(QRegExp("\\[u][0-9]{4}"));
```

It does not remove any instances of \uXXXX where X = numbers.

However, when I am specific such as:

```
myString.remove("\u0006");
```

It does remove it.

Comment: Why not just `"\\u[0-9]{4}"` as a regular expression? Or just `"\\u\\d{4}"`

Comment: maybe two morebackslashes are missing, indeed in a string literal a backslash is an escape character but in a regex too. Does the string actually contains `\u..` or is it a literal? because in the string.remove the sequence is changed to unicode code point

Comment: you should be using QRegularExpression

Comment: @deW1 Are they not synonymous with one another?

Comment: besides what does it say when you match the regex? You should do some debugging

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#notes-for-qregexp-users

Answer (score 0):

String literals are not always the same as character sequence

```
for (char c : "\u0006\u0007\u0013Hello".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println( c + " (" + (int)c + ")" );
}
System.out.println( "--------------" );
for (char c : "\\u0006\\u0007\\u0013Hello".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println( c + " (" + (int)c + ")" );
}
```

In the first example `\u0006` is encoding an unicode code point, whereas in second the string actually contains a backslash.
The string literal only exist at compile time, at runtime they are character sequences.
Regexes are working over character sequence not over string litteral, and also backlash have special meaning and need to be escaped.

Also note that `\u0041` is another way to encode `A`.

Maybe what you are looking for are unicode categories, maybe following can help:

```
string.replaceAll( "\\p{Cc}", "" )
```